# What's wrong with Commons Configuration AbstractConfiguration's get() and getArray()?

Tags: java, arrays, properties-file, apache-commons-config

Using [`commons-configuration2:2.4`](https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:commons-configuration2).

`my.properties`:

```
arrayOfSingle=0xA
arrayOfMultiples=0xD,0xA
```

```
CONFIG.getArray(int[].class, "arrayOfSingle"));

  org.apache.commons.configuration2.ex.ConversionException:
    The value '0xA' (class java.lang.String) can't be converted to a [I object

CONFIG.getArray(int[].class, "arrayOfMultiples"));

  org.apache.commons.configuration2.ex.ConversionException:
    The value '0xD,0xA' (class java.lang.String) can't be converted to a [I object

CONFIG.getArray(Integer[].class, "arrayOfSingle"));

  org.apache.commons.configuration2.ex.ConversionException: 
    The value '0xA' (class java.lang.String) can't be converted to a [Ljava.lang.Integer; object

CONFIG.getArray(Integer[].class, "arrayOfMultiples"));

  org.apache.commons.configuration2.ex.ConversionException:
    The value '0xD,0xA' (class java.lang.String) can't be converted to a [Ljava.lang.Integer; object

CONFIG.get(int[].class, "arrayOfSingle") // prints "[I@7dba7035", i.e.works

CONFIG.get(int[].class, "arrayOfMultiples")

  org.apache.commons.configuration2.ex.ConversionException:
    Could not convert 0xD,0xA to java.lang.Integer! Invalid hex number.

CONFIG.get(Integer[].class, "arrayOfSingle") // prints "[Ljava.lang.Integer;@44d379bb", i.e. works

CONFIG.get(Integer[].class, "arrayOfMultiples")

  org.apache.commons.configuration2.ex.ConversionException:
    Could not convert 0xD,0xA to java.lang.Integer! Invalid hex number.
```

[`getArray(Class<?> cls, String key, Object defaultValue)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/ImmutableConfiguration.html#getArray-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) is deprecated (the use of `get(Class<T> cls, String key, T defaultValue)` is recommended) but `getArray(Class<?> cls, String key)` isn't and `get(Class<T> cls, String key)` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will be useful for those who want to have properties comma-separated as shown below and get List or Array of values.
Even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53431700/2987755) is accepted but if you do not like multiple entries of the same keys then the following solution works.

Add Dependency:

```
compile("org.apache.commons:commons-configuration2:2.7")
```

application.properties file:

```
arrayOfMultiples=0xD,0xA
```

Client:

```java
PropertiesConfiguration propertiesConfiguration = new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<>(PropertiesConfiguration.class)
        .configure(new Parameters()
                .properties()
                .setFileName("application.properties-file-path")
                .setListDelimiterHandler(new DefaultListDelimiterHandler(',')))
        .getConfiguration();
```

output:

```java
propertiesConfiguration.get(Integer[].class, "arrayOfMultiples");
// or
propertiesConfiguration.get(int[].class, "arrayOfMultiples"))
```

> [13, 10]

NOTE: since values are in hexadecimal, the converter converts it to decimal. But works for any int values.

Also works for the following types of read when you need List

```java
propertiesConfiguration.getList(int.class, "arrayOfMultiples");
// or
propertiesConfiguration.getList(Integer.class, "arrayOfMultiples");
```

Answer (score 0):

Abandoning `getArray()` and using the several-lines variant as described in [Lists and arrays](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html#Lists_and_arrays) works.

`my.properties`:

```
arrayOfMultiples=0xD
arrayOfMultiples=0xA
```

```
CONFIG.get(int[].class, "arrayOfMultiples")
CONFIG.get(Integer[].class, "arrayOfMultiples")
```